# Missing jum'ah on Friday

Tags: salat, reference-request, jumuah

Is there a Hadith that you can observe just two rakaat when you get to the mosque shortly after it is concluded

Comment: You need to offer Dhur if you missed Jumah.

Comment: Even if you get to join the Jam'ah but you miss the last Ruku', you still need to offer 4 raka'at of Dhuhr.

Answer (score 2):

You should offer zuhr salah if you miss jum'a salah, even if you reached in the last rak'a of the jum'a salah after ruku, after they finished the salah you stand up and offer 4 rak'a (zuhr salah).